# Retrieve users followers list

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve users followers from Firebase and populate them onto a `RecyclerView` for anyone to be able to see just like twitter and Instagram, when i run the app it returns an error.

My code:

public class ViewFollowersFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "ViewFollowersFragment";

```
private CircleImageView myprofileimage;
private TextView username;
private ImageView arrow;
private ListView vfollowerslistview;
private DatabaseReference viewFollowersref,viewUserRef;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseListAdapter viewfollowersadapter;
private List<User> mUserList;
private User mUser;
String userid;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_followers, container, false);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    vfollowerslistview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.viewfollowerslistview);


    arrow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragfollowersbackarrow);
    arrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    });

    mUserList = new ArrayList<>();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    userid = mAuth.getUid();
    viewFollowersref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User_Account_Settings");

    viewUserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

   setFollowers();


    return view;
}


private void setFollowers () {

    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("Followers")
            .child(mUser.getUser_id());
    FirebaseListOptions<UserAccountSettings> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<UserAccountSettings>()
            .setLayout(R.layout.layout_user_listitem)
            .setLifecycleOwner(getActivity())
            .setQuery(query,UserAccountSettings.class)
            .build();
    viewfollowersadapter = new FirebaseListAdapter(options) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, Object model, final int position) {

            String newfol = getRef(position).getKey();
            final TextView username = v.findViewById(R.id.username);
            final CircleImageView profile_image = v.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);


            viewFollowersref.child(newfol).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("username")) {
                            String myusername = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue().toString();
                            username.setText(myusername);
                        }
                        if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("profileimage")) {
                            String myimage = dataSnapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString();

                            if (myimage.isEmpty()) {
                                profile_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pro_pic);
                            } else {
                                Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(myimage).placeholder(R.drawable.pro_pic).into(profile_image);
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });


            username.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent profileIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ProfileActivity.class);
                    profileIntent.putExtra("calling_activity", "Search_Activity");
                    profileIntent.putExtra("intent_user", mUserList.get(position));
                    startActivity(profileIntent);

                }
            });

            profile_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent profileIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ProfileActivity.class);
                    profileIntent.putExtra("calling_activity", "Search_Activity");
                    profileIntent.putExtra("intent_user", mUserList.get(position));
                    startActivity(profileIntent);

                }
            });

            Query userQuery = viewUserRef
                    .child("Users")
                    .orderByChild("user_id");
            userQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: found user: " +
                                singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getUsername());

                        mUserList.add(singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class));
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }

    };
    vfollowerslistview.setAdapter(viewfollowersadapter);

}
}
```

I cant seem to fit the entirw code in.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: Heres the error ir returns Caused by: java.langCaused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.hope.myapplication.Models.User.getUser_id()' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.hope.myapplication.Utils.ViewFollowersFragment.setFollowers(ViewFollowersFragment.java:100)
                      at com.example.hope.myapplication.Utils.ViewFollowersFragment.onCreateView(ViewFollowersFragment.java:89)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment, you are getting the following error:

> Caused by: java.langCaused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.hope.myapplication.Models.User.getUser_id()' on a null object reference

Because your `mUser` object on which you are calling `getUser_id()` method has the value of `null`. This is happening because you haven't initialized the `User` object in your code at all. To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
        .child("Followers")
        .child(mUser.getUser_id());
```

to

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
        .child("Followers")
        .child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
```

In which `mAuth.getCurrentUser()` return a `FirebaseUser` object, so you can get the correct `uid`.

Comment: The code you gave me displays the current users followers. I want to display the user's followers. I want to display a specific users followers.

Comment: That's right. In that case, you should use instead of `mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()` the uid of the user that you want to display, right?

Comment: I think by mantioning "specific" I made it confusing. what i meant to say was any user. To be able to see any user's followers

Comment: Yes, instead of `mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()`, which is the id of the current logged in user, you should use any other uid of any user. To get that uid, store that uid under each user object in order to be able to use it, right?

Comment: I have exaplained in one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee)** how you can achieve this.

Comment: Is there everything alright, have you solved the issue?

Comment: Apologies i havent had the chance to try it. I will first try the tutorials and then give you feedback. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Hey Alex im dismally failing at this. I tried the code .child (Followers).equalTo(Dy7186gzhnnwyy17); . The Dy71... being the user uid of any user. It just displayed all the users.

Comment: Dy7186gzhnnwyy17 cannot be the id of any user, is not a wildcard is the id of a single user.  You should first get the desired id and then use it in your reference, right?

Comment: It has to be the uid of the desired user? Let me try that

Comment: Hey Alex,sorry to bother you, i just want to ask if it is possible to pass a Parcelable Arraylist by setting an onclicklistener on a textview?

Comment: In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.

Comment: Just posted the question.

Comment: I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write it to you.